# Inheritance mapping Hibernate: Relation mapping between two subclasses

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, design-patterns

I have three entities A, B and C.

```
class A{
     Long id;
}
class B extends A{
   //  var1, var2
   List<C> var0;
}

class C extends A{
    //var 3, var4
    List<B> var5;
}
```

B and C both extends A, also B should contain list of C and C should contain list of B.

Now for inheritance mapping I have used **single table strategy**, as B and C are almost identical.

When I try to define ManyToMany relationship between B and C, so that I can have a mapping of them. My join column have the same name. SO its throwing error which is :
`org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection`

I am not sure if its the right way to do that. Or is there a way around for it?

Comment: I think you only need define one join table on var0 of B or var5 of C.

Comment: @andy Even then, I will have same column names, right?

Comment: I think so, you can have a try.

Comment: on your parent entity try to use @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED) and so u ll have 3 tables